# putting multiple plots in one panel

Tags: r, grid, facet, ggpubr

I am trying to plot a scatter plot in R using ggscatter function from ggpubr package. I am showing you a subset of my data.frame

```
tracking_id gene_short_name B1  B2  C1  C2
ENSG00000000003.14  TSPAN6  1.2 1.16    1.22    1.26
ENSG00000000419.12  DPM1    1.87    1.87    1.68    1.83
ENSG00000000457.13  SCYL3   0.59    0.63    0.82    0.69
ENSG00000000460.16  C1orf112    0.87    0.99    0.97    0.83
ENSG00000001036.13  FUCA2   1.59    1.59    1.4 1.39
ENSG00000001084.10  GCLC    1.43    1.55    1.46    1.32
ENSG00000001167.14  NFYA    1.2 1.3 1.39    1.21
ENSG00000001460.17  STPG1   0.43    0.46    0.34    0.76
ENSG00000001461.16  NIPAL3  0.72    0.84    0.78    0.74
```

I want to make scatter plot between B1 vs B1, B1 vs B2, B1 vs C1, B2 vs C2.

I used the following command

```
df <- read.table(file="transformation.txt",header= TRUE,sep = "\t")
lapply(3:6,  function(X) ggscatter(df, x = "B1", y = colnames(df[X]), add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, 
  cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",add.params = list(color="blue")))
```

I get individual 4 plots. I want to have all 4 plots in 1 plot. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the `grid.arrange()` function in the `gridExtra` package or the `ggarrange()` function in the `ggpubr` package.  This [link](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/) offers some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps mean something like this?

```
library(GGally)
ggpairs(df[, -(1:2)])
```

[image]

[`GGally`](http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/index.html) is a very nice R package offering a lot of customisation options for its plotting routines.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "tracking_id gene_short_name B1  B2  C1  C2
ENSG00000000003.14  TSPAN6  1.2 1.16    1.22    1.26
ENSG00000000419.12  DPM1    1.87    1.87    1.68    1.83
ENSG00000000457.13  SCYL3   0.59    0.63    0.82    0.69
ENSG00000000460.16  C1orf112    0.87    0.99    0.97    0.83
ENSG00000001036.13  FUCA2   1.59    1.59    1.4 1.39
ENSG00000001084.10  GCLC    1.43    1.55    1.46    1.32
ENSG00000001167.14  NFYA    1.2 1.3 1.39    1.21
ENSG00000001460.17  STPG1   0.43    0.46    0.34    0.76
ENSG00000001461.16  NIPAL3  0.72    0.84    0.78    0.74", header = T)
```